# Generate MIPS architecture assembly code on a X86 machine

Tags: compiling, cross-compilation, mips, assembly

I need to generate **MIPS** specific code on my machine when I run my C program. When I simply run,

```
gcc -O2 -S -c hello.c
```

On my system, I get the `hello.s` which seems to generate some assembly code but it doesn't seem to be **MIPS** specific code. The contents of `hello.s` file is as below.

```
    .file   "hello.c"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "Hello world"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB11:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp printf
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE11:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

How can I generate the **MIPS** specific code on my machine?

My machine details are as below.

```
arch
x86_64
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

---

### Understanding the Basics

---

From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set) entry of MIPS architecture, it is described as,

> MIPS (originally an acronym for Microprocessor without Interlocked
>   Pipeline Stages) is a reduced instruction set computer (RISC)
>   instruction set (ISA) developed by MIPS Technologies (formerly MIPS
>   Computer Systems, Inc.).

From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) entry of the x86-64, it is described as,

> x86-64 (also known as x64, x86_64 and AMD64) is the 64-bit version of
>   the x86 instruction set.

So as per the `arch` output in the question, it is evident that I have a **x86_64** machine and I try to produce the **MIPS** architecture specific code after running `gcc` compiler.

This is similar to *trying and running a diesel car on a petrol engine*. No matter how hard we try, without tweaking the gas engine, we could not run the diesel car on a petrol engine.

[To describe it in a technical manner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178160/1742825), `gcc` can produce assembly code for a large number of architectures, include **MIPS**. But what architecture a given `gcc` instance targets is decided when `gcc` itself is compiled. The precompiled binary you will find in an Ubuntu system knows about **x86** (possibly both 32-bit and 64-bit modes) but not **MIPS**.

---

### How to compile a C program to MIPS assembly code

---

Again quoting from the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178160/1742825), compiling `gcc` with a target architecture distinct from the architecture on which `gcc` itself will be running is known as preparing a cross-compilation toolchain. Or in layman's terms, *this cross compilation toolchain is similar to tweaking the petrol engine to run the diesel car*.

However, setting up a cross-compilation toolchain is quite a bit of work, so rather than describe how to set that up, I will describe how to install a native MIPS compiler into a MIPS virtual machine.  This involves the additional steps of setting up an emulator for the VM and installing an OS into that environment, but will allow you to use a pre-built native compiler rather than compiling a cross compiler.

We will be first installing `qemu` to make our system run some virtualized operating systems. Again there are several approaches like installing some cross compiled tool chain as [discussed here](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains) and [using a buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) as suggested in the answer that I earlier linked.

- Download the tar ball of [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Download) from here.
- After downloading the tar ball, run the following commands.

  ```
   bzip2 -d qe*
   tar -xvf qe*
   ./configure
   make
   make install
  ```
- Now, after installing `qemu` on the machine, I tried several methods
  of netboot for the debian OS as suggested over
  [here](https://gmplib.org/~tege/qemu.html) and
  [here](http://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_mips_qemu.php). But
  unfortunately I was not able to perform the debian OS installation
  using the netboot because the correct mirrors were not available.

I got an image for debian which targets MIPS architecture from
   [here](https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/mips/) and I
   downloaded the `kernel` and `qemu` image and  from the above link and performed the below steps.

- I started the `qemu` as below.

  ```
  qemu-system-mips -M malta -kernel vmlinux-2.6.32-5-4kc-malta -hda 
  debian_squeeze_mips_standard.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0"
  ```
- After the debian system came up, I installed the `gcc` compiler as
  below.

  ```
  apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
  apt-get install build-essential
  ```

Now, I have a perfectly working native `gcc` compiler inside the MIPS debian virtual machine on qemu, which compiles my C program to **MIPS** specific assembly code.

---

### Testing

---

Inside my debian machine, I just put in a sample C hello world program and saved it as `hello.c` as below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

To generate MIPS architecture code for my hello.c program, I ran the C program using the `gcc` compiler as,

```
gcc -O2 -S -c hello.c
```

The above command generated a `hello.s` file which generated my **MIPS** architecture code.

```
    .file   1 "hello.c"
    .section .mdebug.abi32
    .previous
    .gnu_attribute 4, 1
    .abicalls
    .section    .rodata.str1.4,"aMS",@progbits,1
    .align  2
$LC0:
    .ascii  "Hello World\000"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .set    nomips16
    .ent    main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    .frame  $sp,0,$31       # vars= 0, regs= 0/0, args= 0, gp= 0
    .mask   0x00000000,0
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro

    lui $28,%hi(__gnu_local_gp)
    addiu   $28,$28,%lo(__gnu_local_gp)
    lui $4,%hi($LC0)
    lw  $25,%call16(printf)($28)
    nop
    jr  $25
    addiu   $4,$4,%lo($LC0)

    .set    macro
    .set    reorder
    .end    main
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5"
```

But how will I know if the above generated code is **MIPS** assembly code?

The `arch` command's output will tell the machine's architecture. In my debian machine, it produces the output as `mips` and I also do not have any `binutils` or cross-compiler tool chains installed in the machine.

So, the generated assembly code is **MIPS** specific.

Comment: This is good and working but is *native* inside a vm (slower), in newer Debians with multi-arch support theoretically should be *easy* to get a [toolchain](https://wiki.debian.org/MultiarchCrossToolchainBuild#Local_building_of_multiarch_cross-toolchains) (but I've a feeling isn't still that easy.. never checked)

Comment: @Alex, I would say getting a tool chain is a tad easier compared to building our own tool chain.

Comment: sure, my understanding is that pre-built like codesourcery are also optmized to produce better code. I'm trying the Debian build process which seems to work fine, eventually I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need a cross toolchain, gcc (+binutils) which run on x86_64 but output mips binaries.

You can try to build it yourself from scratch (google for examples: build cross toolchain) or download a pre-built one (like from [Codesourcery](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/codesourcery))

Or you may build your own with the help of some tool like [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/)

Also systems like [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) build (or download) their own cross toolchain (I guess also OpenWRT).

Comment: thanks. I had checked the codesourcery tool chain. But I guess it is not available for free.

Comment: @Ramesh the Lite version is for free, and it is good (my old company used it on production for years), I'm not sure it is available for x86_64 but maybe you can get the ia32(ix86) working. You didn't mention in your question but, what is the target hw/arch?

Answer (score 2):

The [emdebian](http://www.emdebian.org/) project has done some work on [cross toolchains](http://emdebian.org/crosstools.html).

As these packages suffer from bit rot quite heavily, I'd inquire about the current status with the emdebian project, either via mailing list or IRC.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please add the relevant information from the link to the answer so that it would be useful for future readers?

Comment: @Ramesh, I'm not sure that's a good idea. Toolchain compilation is a moving target, and any reference that is not actively maintained becomes unusable rather quickly.